# Nginx status is active but it is not serving

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, hosting

I have attached two files in which I am hosting var/www/html files and localhost/:3000

please help me why nginx not serving when i am hitting ip of server.

Is there any solution for my problem if so then let me know what changes should I do so that it will work

I have configure port 81 for this application

nginx.conf

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
worker_connections 768;
 # multi_accept on;
}

http {

 ##
 # Basic Settings
 ##

sendfile on;
tcp_nopush on;
tcp_nodelay on;
keepalive_timeout 65;
types_hash_max_size 2048;
 # server_tokens off;

 # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
 # server_name_in_redirect off;

include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type application/octet-stream;

 ##
 # SSL Settings
 ##

ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

 ##
 # Logging Settings
 ##

access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

 ##
 # Gzip Settings
 ##

gzip on
 # gzip_vary on;
 # gzip_proxied any;
 # gzip_comp_level 6;
 # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
 # gzip_http_version 1.1;
 # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml>

 ##
 # Virtual Host Configs
 ##

include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

sites-enabled file

```
server {
listen 81 default_server;
listen [::]:81 default_server;
root /var/www/html;

 # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
index index.php;

server_name _;

location / {
 # First attempt to serve request as file, then
 # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?args;
}
location /front/ {
proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
}
 # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
 #
location ~ \.php$ {
include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
 #       # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
 #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
}

 # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
 # concurs with nginx's one
 #
location ~ /\.ht {
deny all;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your NGINX config you've set port 81 but you're trying to hit port 3000?

Other than that verify

1. If the files working within the server? Like CURL or WGET
2. Make sure you've configured the security group to open the correct port for incoming traffic
3. Make sure that you're using PUBLIC IP of your instance
4. Make sure that your instance have access to server (should be in public subnet)

Even after all this if it doesn't work then update the question with more details as to exact error message.

Comment: actually, I am passing the proxy localhost/3000 to work on /front route

Comment: and security groups are configured correctly